# How do I add mac tag to AES with GCM-mode

Tags: kotlin, encryption, bouncycastle

I have used bouncycastle to create a encryption scheme that looks like this:

```
fun enc(plaintext : ByteArray, key : Key,iv : ByteArray) : ByteArray{
    val cipher : Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NOPADDING  ")

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, IvParameterSpec(iv))
    return cipher.doFinal(plaintext)
}

fun dec(ciphertext : ByteArray, key: Key, iv : ByteArray) : String {
    val cipher : Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NOPADDING ")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, IvParameterSpec(iv))
    return String(cipher.doFinal(ciphertext))
}
```

and then I use this drivercode to run things:

```
Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleFipsProvider())
val key2 : Key = SecretKeySpec(Hex.decode("e6d4d9472cf9b7a92a652fc7e1f3b4124906cff47f42115d77d64709f2177503"), "AES")

val iv : ByteArray =    Hex.decode("a2d21879269610eab7c16250b3b4bd81fc41b99738d7f8f2966ecd0bb2e5682a")


val ciphertext  =  encTWO("12345678123456781234567812345678".toByteArray(), key2, iv)
val decryptedText = decTWO(a, key2,iv)

println(Hex.toHexString(ciphertext))
print(decryptedText)
```

I need to add a tag (which I understand is a mac to this), preferably of 128 bits added to this scheme, but I really cant figure out how? The documentation is very sparse and I cant find any examples doing it

EDIT:

I now understand that the mac tag is sent, concatenated to the end of the ciphertext, I have these:

```
fun encGCM(plaintext : ByteArray, key : Key,iv : ByteArray) : ByteArray{
    val cipher : Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NOPADDING  ")

    val keyBytes : ByteArray = ByteArray(keylength)
    random.nextBytes(keyBytes)
    val macspec : GCMParameterSpec = GCMParameterSpec(128, iv )
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, macspec)
    return cipher.doFinal(plaintext)
}

fun decGCM(ciphertext : ByteArray, key: Key, iv : ByteArray) : String {
    val cipher : Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NOPADDING ")
    val macspec : GCMParameterSpec = GCMParameterSpec(128, iv )

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, macspec)
    return String(cipher.doFinal(ciphertext))

}
```

Comment: The tag is _implicitly_ generated during encryption and appended to the ciphertext. Therefore the ciphertext length is equal to the plaintext length plus the tag length. During decryption, the ciphertext plus the appended tag must be passed. Furthermore: Recommended IV length for GCM is 12 bytes. A key/IV pair must _strictly_ not be used more than once for GCM (use a _random_ IV for _each_ encryption). Replace `IvParameterSpec` (tag length by default 16 bytes) better by `GCMParameterSpec` (tag length is specified in the first parameter in bits).

Comment: Ok, so i can understand that the tag is already being created, thats great, im halfway there then.
But my question still stands, how do I get ahold of this tag that you say that I should be passing around?

Comment: As said, the encryption (`cipher.doFinal()`) returns the ciphertext with the tag attached: _ciphertext | tag_. During decryption, this construct is to be passed in the same way, i.e. ciphertext with the tag attached. Therefore, a separation of ciphertext and tag is not necessary here. However, there are libraries that process ciphertext and tag separately. In this case you have to separate both, which is no problem, because the tag length is known.

Comment: ah, all right, so it is concatenated to the end of the cipher? am i correct in assuming that the difference between GCMParameterSpec and IvParameterSpec is the in GCMParameterSpec, that i can specify the length of the mac tag that is generated anyway?

Comment: Right, the concatenation is _ciphertext | tag_. `GCMParameterSpec` allows the specification of the tag length, `IvParameterSpec` uses 16 bytes by default. With Android both can be used for GCM, with Java `IvParameterSpec` generally gives an error.